# Display php browser content successively

Tags: php, oracle, performance

I'm currently migrating a webpage to a new server from php 5.0.x to php 5.6

Now I got one page that loops a Database query 7 times and the results are loaded into a table. I know that this is not the best way of doing things but it works quite well and I currently don't have other options to work on that because the results come from different databases. Caching is not an option because I need the content always up to date.

From accessing the site until it is displayed it takes around three to four seconds.. The queries got optimized recently but still take a long time to get executed.

To my problem: The old webserver shows the result table by table, so the user see's that the page is already working on it's request. When the content of Table1 is loaded, it gets displayed and the server cares for the second resultset.

The new webserver generates the website at once and the content is not shown until the 7 resultsets are loaded and the data is mapped to the grids.

Is there an option, maybe in `php.ini` with that i can reach the same result as on the old webserver? I really dunno how to google it so I'm asking you guys.

On the other hand maybe there's an option to run all the queries at once (multithreading?) and not in sequence?

Sorry for my "improvable" english.

Comment: Is it possible to show your code ?

Comment: Not the way it's written but I can try to anonymize it. The code itself didn't change since the old webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably something related to output buffering. You can force to write buffer contents out to the client with [ob_flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) function, just add a call to ob_flush after query execution.

php.ini setting is output_buffering. Also check output_compression setting, as it can cause problems with buffer flush.

Comment: The `output_buffering` was set to 4096 bytes and `output_compression` is deactivated on the new webserver and on the old one as well but `ob_flush()` did the job! Thank you!